# hive query for derived columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery, bigdata, derived-column

Could you please guide.

Input table (Table1) have columns like credit_date, credit_amount, debit_date, debit_amount, loan_date, loan_amount.

Output table(Table 2) have columns like date, credit_payment, Debit_payment, Loan_payment.

**Date** : should combine all values of credit_date, debit_date and loan_date.

**Credit_payment**: Find the sum of credit amount for a given credit_date.

**Debit_payment:** Find the sum of debit amount for a given debit_date.

**Loan_payment:** Find the sum of loan amount for a given loan_date

I tried below query but not working.

```
insert into table2 
select 
date,
debit_payment,
credit_payment,
Loan_payment
 from (
select 
sum(credit_amount) over parttion by credit_date as credit_payment,
sum(debit_amount) over parttion by debit_date as Debit_payment
sum(loan_amount) over parttion by loan_date as Loan_payment
from table1
union all
select credit_date as date from table1
union all
select debit_date as date from table1
union all
select payment_date as date from table1
) t
```

[image]

**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I have another scenario where credit_Date, debit_date and loan_date can be same.
Output table have below columns

**Date:** should combine credit_date, debit_date and loan_date (
credit_date, debit_date and loan_date can be same or different also)

**Credit_payment:**Find the sum of credit amount for a given credit_date, entity, currency, owner

**Debit_payment:** Find the sum of debit amount for a given debit_date, entity, currency, owner

**Loan_payment:** Find the sum of loan amount for a given loan_date, entity, currency, owner,

**entity:** values from Table1

**currency :** values from Table 1

**Owner:** values from Table 1

**Total :** sum of ( credit_payment + debit_payement+ loan_payment)

could you please guide.

Please find the screenshot as below.

[image]

Comment: @mck

Thanks for your response


I have below question

why to add select * ?

insert into table2 
select *
date,
debit_payment,
credit_payment,
Loan_payment
 from (
select 
sum(credit_amount) over parttion by credit_date as credit_payment,
sum(debit_amount) over parttion by debit_date as Debit_payment
sum(loan_amount) over parttion by loan_date as Loan_payment
from table1
union all
select credit_date as date from table1
union all
select debit_date as date from table1
union all
select payment_date as date from table1
) t

Comment: that was your original code... I just changed that to code formatting so that it's easier to read

Comment: you can edit your question to correct it

Comment: @mck I have another scenario where the `credit_date`, `loan_date` and `payment_date` can be same. Also added few other columns like entity, currency, owner and total to the output table. in this case `union all` is not fetching expected results. Could you please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to explicitly specify the null columns before you do union all:

```sql
insert into table2 
select *
from (
    select credit_date as date, sum(credit_amount) as credit_payment, null as debit_payment, null as loan_payment
    from table1
    group by credit_date
    union all
    select debit_date as date, null as credit_payment, sum(debit_amount) as debit_payment, null as loan_payment
    from table1
    group by debit_date 
    union all
    select loan_date as date, null as credit_payment, null as debit_payment, sum(loan_amount) as loan_payment
    from table1
    group by loan_date
) t
order by date;
```

Comment: Thanks @mck for response.

I have a doubt.
Is sum over partition by  a better approach than Group by in case of huge volume of data?

Comment: You need a group by because you only want one row for each date. `sum over partition by` will give the original number of rows, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: I have another scenario where the credit_date, loan_date and payment_date can be same. Also added few other columns like entity, currency, owner and total to the output table. in this case uniion all is not fetching expected results. Could you please guide

Comment: Added a new ques
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526059/hive-query-for-derived-columns-and-find-the-total-of-derived-column