# Hive (hql) for derived columns and find the total

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery, bigdata, derived-column

Could you please guide

I have a scenario where credit_Date,debit_date and loan_date can have different values of date or same. Output table have below columns

**Date:** should combine credit_date, debit_date and loan_date ( credit_date, debit_date and loan_date can be **same** (or) have **different dates**)

**Credit_payment:** Find the sum of credit amount for a given credit_date, entity, currency, owner

**Debit_payment:** Find the sum of debit amount for a given debit_date, entity, currency, owner

**Loan_payment:** Find the sum of loan amount for a given loan_date, entity, currency, owner,

**entity:** values from Table1

**currency** : values from Table 1

**Owner:** values from Table 1

**Total :** sum of ( credit_payment + debit_payement+ loan_payment)

Please find the screenshot as below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a similar query as in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66526897/14165730), and change the format of `table1` in order to facilitate grouping by date:

```sql
select coalesce(credit_date, debit_date, loan_date) as date, 
       coalesce(sum(credit_amount), 0) as credit_payment, 
       coalesce(sum(debit_amount), 0) as debit_payment,
       coalesce(sum(loan_amount), 0) as loan_payment,
       entity, currency, owner,
       coalesce(sum(credit_amount), 0) + coalesce(sum(debit_amount), 0) + coalesce(sum(loan_amount), 0) as Total
from (
    select credit_date, credit_amount, null as debit_date, null as debit_amount, null as loan_date, null as loan_amount, entity, currency, owner
    from table1
    union all
    select null as credit_date, null as credit_amount, debit_date, debit_amount, null as loan_date, null as loan_amount, entity, currency, owner
    from table1
    union all
    select null as credit_date, null as credit_amount, null as debit_date, null as debit_amount, loan_date, loan_amount, entity, currency, owner
    from table1
) t
group by coalesce(credit_date, debit_date, loan_date), entity, currency, owner
```

Comment: Thank @mck for the response.

When I am executing above query, it's populating the values of `credit_date` for the date column in the table2.  we need to populate all the values of `credit_date`, `debit_date`, `loan_date` in the `date` column of `table2`.  Could you please guide.

Comment: the credit_date and debit_date and loan_date are of datatype string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem... I tested on the sample data you provided and it gave the expected output. Could you describe your problem in more details please?

Comment: Thanks for the response @mck

I have posted another query. Could you please guide.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548308/hive-hql-for-derived-columns

Comment: Hi @smp97 would you mind posting sample data in text format? It's hard to read the excel screenshot.

Comment: Sure... could you please tell me how to post tables in .txt format!?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Thanks... I've updated the table in txt format... but table-1 is having some issues updating correctly..

Comment: you need an empty new line before the table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229710/discussion-between-smp97-and-mck).